# how to open a app in floating window from my app on button click in android?

Tags: android

How to create an app which opens another app from my activity in Android?
as an example, I want the Gmail app to open in my app with a floating view

```
  button.setOnClickListener {
        if (canDrawOverlays) {
            simpleFloatingWindow.show()
        } 
    }

  simple floating window, I want to show another application in this window,
  I can create a floating view but how to open an app in that?
  Please suggest how to do that or any other suggestions for this type of functionality.
```